# How to exclude a task from the task that a separate task dependsOn?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle task that depends on the `build` of another subproject. But the subproject build contains `test` task which I do not require. How to exclude the test task from the subproject build task that my gradle task is dependent on.

This is how my task looks :

```
task mainTask( type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn ':subProjectA:build'
```

I tried using gradle `taskGraph` but didn't work out. I did something like this :

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(mainTask)) {
        tasks.withType(Test){
            enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

After including the `taskGraph` configuration, still the tests from the subProject test task run.

Is there a way to exclude the subProject tests from running, while having the dependency of the subProject build in my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below seems to work

```
task mainTask() {
    dependsOn ':sub1:build'
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    println "checking graph"
    if (graph.hasTask(mainTask)) {
        graph.getAllTasks().findAll { it.path == ':sub1:test' }.forEach {
            println ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> setting disabled - $it.name"
            it.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it.